# Pentax DSLR stopped accepting manual lenses

Tags: old-lenses, pentax

I've upgraded K-S1 camera firmware to latest version, played with some settings and reset them to defaults.
For some reasons, manual (K) lenses aren't accepted anymore. Modern auto-focus lenses work fine but for my old lenses, the camera doesn't show focal length setting when turned on. Display shows flashing F-- and I can't take pictures in any mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use manual (K) lenses, `Using Aperture Ring` in menu C4 - 26 needs to be enabled (not enabled by default) - check [user's manual](http://www.ricoh-imaging.co.jp/english/support/man-pdf/k-s1.pdf), p. 85 - Setting the Focal Length.